# Warum die Kombination bei "Gefahr in Verzug"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Der Begriff "Gefahr in Verzug" ist allgemein bekannt, obwohl er eher ein juristicher Fachbegriff ist. Er bedeutet, dass unter gewissen Voraussetzungen ("wenn in der Zeit von der richterlichen Unterrichtung bis zu deren Entscheidung mit einer Flucht, einem Verlust von Beweismitteln oder einem Schaden an einem Rechtsgut zu rechnen ist") eine Durchsuchung auch ohne richterlichen Beschluss erfolgen darf.

Wie passt das Wort "Verzug" in diesen Kontext? Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verzug) steht Verzug für:

- allgemein die Verzögerung einer fälligen Leistung, Schuldnerverzug, siehe Vertragsverletzung
- speziell in Bezug auf die Ware oder Dienstleistung der Lieferverzug
- speziell in Bezug auf die Abgeltung der Zahlungsverzug
- die Weigerung des Gläubigers, eine Leistung entgegenzunehmen, Gläubigerverzug, siehe Annahmeverzug
- im Verfahrensrecht eine Hinauszögerung im Tätigwerden, siehe Gefahr im Verzug
- in der Mechanik eine Änderung der Maße und der Form, siehe Verzug (Mechanik)
- bei Papier eine Änderung der Maße, siehe Papierverzug
- in der Garnherstellung das Auseinanderziehen der Fasern eines Faserbandes zu einem feineren Band, siehe Verzug (Garnherstellung)
- im Bergbau die Auskleidung der Zwischenräume beim Streckenausbau, siehe Verzug (Bergbau)

Also:

"Zahlung in Verzug" - die veinbarte Zahlung ist noch nicht erfolgt.

"Projekt in Verzug" - die zugesagte Projektfertigstellung ist noch nicht erfolgt.

In dieses Schema passt "Gefahr" in Verzug" nicht. Man kann natürlich akzeptieren, dass die Formulierung nun einmal so ist. Aber irgendeine Vorstellung sollte doch damit verbunden gewesen sein. Eine bessere Formulierung wäre m.E. "Die Gefahr liegt in einem Verzug", d.h. in einer Verzögerung polizeilichen Handelns. Das ist zwar länger, aber Juristen haben sonst auch keine Scheu vor Längen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laut [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=verzug) handelt es sich bei *Gefahr im Verzug* um eine Lehnübersetzung von lat. *periculum in mora*, *Gefahr ist [liegt] im Verzug* oder freier *Aufschub bedeutet Gefahr*.

*Verzug* wird in dieser Wendung also in seiner primären Bedeutung als *Aufschub, Verzögerung* gebraucht. Bis auf die Auslassung des finiten Verbs ist die Bedeutung transparent.

Wie der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verzug) mit der Periphrase *Gefahr droht* andeutet, hat sich inzwischen allerdings eine idiomatische, also nicht herleitbare Bedeutung etabliert (entweder, weil Sprechern das Wort *Verzug* nicht mehr bekannt ist oder weil sie die Auslassung des finiten Verbs nicht richtig interpretieren).

Comment: Die Lehnsübersetzung ist eine sehr überzeugende  Begründung.

Answer (score 4):

Der Verzug ist hier die Ursache der Gefahr, in Deutschland heisst es normalerweise auch "Gefahr **im** Verzug". Die eigentliche Betonung des Ausdrucks auf "Verzug", nicht auf "Gefahr" macht das noch deutlicher, auch wenn man meistens anders spricht. Gemeint ist, dass ein Schaden entsteht, wenn nicht unmittelbar (vor Ort) gehandelt wird, obwohl eigentlich eine andere Stelle oder Person handeln oder entscheiden müsste.

Comment: "Gefahr **im** Verzug" ist tatsächlich etwas deutlicher. Mit einer Google-Suche erkennt man, dass die vom mir verwendete Variante "Gefahr in Verzug" in Österreich üblich ist. Interessant - ich bin kein Österreicher, aber irgendwie klang das für mich so richtig.

Answer (score 2):

> - im Verfahrensrecht eine Hinauszögerung im Tätigwerden, siehe Gefahr im Verzug
>
> ...
>
> Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass mit "Gefahr in Verzug" gemeint ist, dass die Gefahr sich bei Untätigkeit der Polizei "verzieht" (im Sinne von "die Gefahr verschwindet").

Nein, es bedeutet eher das Gegenteil von *Verschwinden der Gefahr*. Im Falle der Untätigkeit würde die Gefahr (z.B. für die Unversehrtheit von Leib und Leben, oder einer Flucht eines Tatverdächtigen) eintreten.

So dürfen zum Beispiel Polizeibeamte in eine Wohnung auch ohne Durchsuchungsbefehl (die Beantragung desselben bei der Staatsanwaltschaft / einem Richter würde einen *Verzug* bedeuten) eindringen (notfalls mit Gewalt), sobald der dringende Verdacht besteht, dass eine Person in dieser Wohnung in Gefahr ist.

Comment: Die Bedeutung ist mir klar - nur nicht, warum das Wort Verzug hier benutzt wird. Mit dem gängigen Verständnis von Verzug als Verzögerung klingt die Kombination "Gefahr in Verzug" schief. Ich stelle das noch in meiner Frage klar.

Comment: Ist natürlich unschön, wenn Fragen nachträglich geändert werden ... Danke für die Antwort.